# jquery function not working on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery function and it does not work,

```
$(document).on('click',"#btn_submit",function(){
        $('.task_members_'+$(this).parent().parent().find('.j').val()).val(selectedImgsArr);
      var select_status = ("#label_task").val();
      var j = $(".j").attr('value');
      var url = "<?php echo $this->Url->build(array('controller' => 'dashboards','action'=>'addarraysessionproject'))?>";

         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          async : false,
          data: {
                  array_user : selectedImgsArr,
                  array_status : custom_array,
                  select_status : select_status,
                  'j': j
                },
          success:function(data){
          }
      });
        $('.close').click();
    });
```

Please let me know where i'm going wrong.

Comment: 1) Please describe your problem. What is happening? What is not happening? What do you expect to happen? 2) Remove `async: false`. It horrendous to use, and you'll get warnings in the console about it 3) Check the console for errors and update your question to include any you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,i think its mistake on line var select_status

```
$(document).on('click',"#btn_submit",function(){
        $('.task_members_'+$(this).parent().parent().find('.j').val()).val(selectedImgsArr);
      var select_status = $("#label_task").val();
      var j = $(".j").attr('value');
      var url = "<?php echo $this->Url->build(array('controller' => 'dashboards','action'=>'addarraysessionproject'))?>";

         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          async : false,
          data: {
                  array_user : selectedImgsArr,
                  array_status : custom_array,
                  select_status : select_status,
                  'j': j
                },
          success:function(data){
          }
      });
        $('.close').click();
    });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!